# Selecting the count and a column value if the count is > 0

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT
    case when count(*) > 0 then 'Y' else 'N' end exists,
    column
FROM
    table
WHERE
    condition;
```

This doesn't work because I don't have a group by function. But if I group on "column" then I get 0 rows if the condition is not met. I know that my query will ever only return one row but even if I make the query only select the first row it still says it needs a group by function.

My ideal output from the query would be

> 'Y' | 1

if the row exists and

> 'N' | null

if it doesn't

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
SELECT (case when count(*) > 0 then 'Y' else 'N' end) as exists,
       MAX(column) as column
FROM table
WHERE condition;
```

An aggregation query with no `GROUP BY` always returns one row.

Comment: I agree this is the best solution. When you are guaranteed a single row, then using MAX() must give you the value of the column. The maximum in a set with a single value must be that value.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    case when count(*) > 0 then 'Y' else 'N' end exists,
    max(1) as column
FROM
    table
WHERE
    condition;
```

this returns Y | 1 when the condition is met.